# Node Mongo inserts start to fail silently after a few minutes

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I am running a GPS listener program. It receives data from GPS devices, decodes, prepares a final data object and then stores the data in Database.
I am trying to insert documents to mongodb from nodejs with the following code - (using node mongodb native driver)

```
var mong = require('mongodb');
var MongoClient = mongo.MongoClient
, format = require('util').format;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://user:pass@a.b.c.d:27017/dbname', function(err, db) {
        if(err) {console.log("mongo connect error " + err); throw err};

        gpsdb = db;
        console.log("Database Ready");
        listener.listen(port);
        console.log("Listener Started on: " + port);
    });

// code to generate the object to insert - d_obj

var collection = gpsdb.collection(d_obj);
d_obj._id = new mong.ObjectID;
collection.insert(d_obj, {safe:true}, function(err, docs) {
    if (err) { console.log("mongo insert query error " + err); return; }
    console.log("Inserted 1 rec " + d_obj.imei);
    console.dir(docs);

});
```

The inserts happen for 2-3 minutes after starting the program. After that insertion stops. However, the console logs keep coming.

Sample Log -

```
Inserted 1 rec 358811020044291
[ { dt_server: '2014-12-12 05:56:14',
 dt_tracker: '2014-12-12 05:56:09',
 lat: 19.123456,
 lng: 73.123456,
 angle: 81,
 speed: '47',
 signal_gsm: 3,
 signal_gps: 4,
 alarm: 'pcut',
 odo: 'y',
 offset: 0,
 time_stamp: 1418363774454,
 ltime: '2014-12-12 05:56:09',
 proto: 12,
 imei: '123456789123456',
 save_mysql: 'no',
 altitude: 0,
 _id: 548a837e4c73ebaef72d0073 } ]
```

The console.dir(doc) should execute only if the query was executed properly. 
I am not getting any errors or warnings. I am getiing this console log for every data object processed.
But Inserts are not happening after the first few minutes.

When I test the program with 1 device sending data, it works flawlessly for hours. All data is inserted properly. 
But when I run it with about 2000 devices connected, the silent fail happens.

I have tried by removing the properties from the data object (d_obj) which has null value. That did not help.

I have not defined any schema or data types anywhere.

**Possible Reason**

It seems to be a locking issue for async inserts. My program on nodejs sends many parallel inserts.
When I run the program normally (in async manner), following is the mongostat output -

```
connected to: 127.0.0.1
insert  query update delete getmore command flushes mapped  vsize    res faults        locked db idx miss %     qr|qw   ar|aw  netIn netOut  conn set repl       time 
138     *0      1     *0      43    28|0       0   496g   992g  10.8g      1 ilogistek:144.8%          0       4|0     0|1    93k   101k    40 rs0  PRI   00:15:12 
143     *0      1     *0      70    73|0       0   496g   992g  10.8g      1 ilogistek:176.2%          0       6|0     0|1   106k   108k    40 rs0  PRI   00:15:13 
125     *0      1     *0      60    60|0       0   496g   992g  10.9g      2 ilogistek:124.2%          0       5|0     0|1    94k    95k    40 rs0  PRI   00:15:14 
181     *0      1     *0      77    96|0       0   496g   992g    11g      0 ilogistek:149.8%          0       6|0     0|1   135k   137k    40 rs0  PRI   00:15:15 
91     *0      1     *0      47    45|0       0   496g   992g  11.1g      0 ilogistek:127.0%          0       6|0     0|1    68k    70k    40 rs0  PRI   00:15:16 
211     *0      3     *0      74    94|0       0   496g   992g  11.2g      2 ilogistek:138.6%          0       6|0     0|1   152k   156k    40 rs0  PRI   00:15:18 
250     *0      2     *0      71    86|0       0   496g   992g  11.2g      5 ilogistek:203.9%          0      10|0     0|1   174k   176k    40 rs0  PRI   00:15:19 
270     *0      3     *0      76   111|0       0   496g   992g  10.9g      3  ilogistek:99.2%          0       5|0     0|1   197k   200k    40 rs0  PRI   00:15:20 
137     *0      3     *0      54    48|0       0   496g   992g  10.9g      8 ilogistek:137.7%          0       5|0     0|1    97k   100k    40 rs0  PRI   00:15:21 
203     *0      1     *0      83   114|0       0   496g   992g    11g      9 ilogistek:154.8%          0       4|0     0|1   153k   152k    40 rs0  PRI   00:15:22
```

On The other hand, when I force the writes in a synchronous manner (next write goes at the callback of the previous write), the locking does not happen and writes per second increases many times.

```
insert  query update delete getmore command flushes mapped  vsize    res faults       locked db idx miss %     qr|qw   ar|aw  netIn netOut  conn set repl       time 
1670     *0      1     *0     321   515|0       0   496g   992g  11.4g      0 ilogistek:15.7%          0       0|0     0|0     1m     1m    19 rs0  PRI   00:24:47 
1830     *0      1     *0     344   621|0       0   496g   992g  11.4g      0 ilogistek:10.3%          0       0|0     0|0     1m     1m    19 rs0  PRI   00:24:48 
1767     *0      1     *0     330   571|0       0   496g   992g  11.4g      1 ilogistek:14.5%          0       0|0     0|0     1m     1m    19 rs0  PRI   00:24:49 
1726     *0      1     *0     337   599|0       0   496g   992g  11.4g      0 ilogistek:11.9%          0       0|0     0|0     1m     1m    19 rs0  PRI   00:24:50 
1743     *0      1     *0     343   590|0       0   496g   992g  11.4g      0 ilogistek:10.9%          0       0|0     0|0     1m     1m    19 rs0  PRI   00:24:51 
1758     *0      1     *0     336   605|0       0   496g   992g  11.4g      0 ilogistek:12.2%          0       0|0     0|0     1m     1m    19 rs0  PRI   00:24:52 
1657     *0      1     *0     344   625|0       0   496g   992g  11.4g      0  ilogistek:9.9%          0       0|0     0|1     1m     1m    19 rs0  PRI   00:24:53 
1688     *0      1     *0     342   567|0       0   496g   992g  11.4g      0 ilogistek:10.6%          0       0|0     0|0     1m     1m    19 rs0  PRI   00:24:54 
1689     *0      1     *0     344   610|0       0   496g   992g  11.4g      0 ilogistek:10.1%          0       0|0     0|0     1m     1m    19 rs0  PRI   00:24:55 
1780     *0      1     *0     340   596|0       0   496g   992g  11.4g      0 ilogistek:10.8%          0       0|0     0|0     1m     1m    19 rs0  PRI   00:24:56
```

I cannot run my program in a synchronous manner as that will beat the very purpose of this technology stack.

Is there something obvious I am missing.

Gurus, please help!

Comment: Can this be a locking issue? I am using Mongo 2.6 version. There is no lock related error or warning message similar to "Lock wait timeout" message of mysql in the program log.

Comment: I have not enabled Journaling in the query. I do not know if it is enabled in the mongodb. Also worth mentioning is that this is a 2 machine replica setup. I am trying to write to the primary and hoping that writes will be synced to the replica system automatically without any specific code in the query.

Comment: I have not done any indexing on my collections except for the _id field. Will that help?
From MongoDb Official Site, I read this (below) and hence did not do indexing. This is absolutely killing my read speeds, but I will cross one bridge at a time.

"
After every insert, update, or delete operation, MongoDB must update every index associated with the collection in addition to the data itself. Therefore, every index on a collection adds some amount of overhead for the performance of write operations."